# VS 2015 compiling cocos2d-x 3.3 error "fatal error C1189: #error: Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration"

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, visual-studio-2015

When I compile cocos2d-x (version 3.3) using visual studio 2015, an error occured, saying:

> fatal error C1189: #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration (编译源文件 ..\base\s3tc.cpp)

The source code is:

```
#ifdef snprintf
    #error Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library 
             function declaration
#endif
```

Anybody can tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 62):

Until now, Many libraries & programs used `snprintf()` function by defining it as `_snprintf()`, since `_snprintf()` was supported.

```
#define snprintf _snprintf
```

Finally, Visual Studio 14 defines `snprintf()`!

Since, `snprintf()` is now officially supported. We should never #define it.

Doing it will overshadow new `snprintf()` function defined in stdio.h.

To restrict that, this is added in stdio.h

```
#ifdef snprintf
    #error: Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration”
#endif
```

Hence, your code doesn't compile.

It is true that on all previous versions of Visual Studio, you must use `_snprintf()` function. But VS 2014 onwards you should not #define it with `_snprintf()`.

Somewhere in your code or most likely in `cocos` headers, this is done and hence the error.

Check that and remove that #define.

`snprintf()` is part of C99 specifications.

To enable C99 support

add this in your program

```
#if _MSC_VER>=1900
#  define STDC99
#endif
```

In case you don't know what _MSC_VER macro values are

```
...
MSVC++ 14.0 _MSC_VER == 1900 (Visual Studio 2015)
MSVC++ 12.0 _MSC_VER == 1800 (Visual Studio 2013)
MSVC++ 11.0 _MSC_VER == 1700 (Visual Studio 2012)
MSVC++ 10.0 _MSC_VER == 1600 (Visual Studio 2010)
MSVC++ 9.0  _MSC_VER == 1500 (Visual Studio 2008)
MSVC++ 8.0  _MSC_VER == 1400 (Visual Studio 2005)
MSVC++ 7.1  _MSC_VER == 1310 (Visual Studio .NET 2003)
MSVC++ 7.0  _MSC_VER == 1300
MSVC++ 6.0  _MSC_VER == 1200
MSVC++ 5.0  _MSC_VER == 1100
MSVC++ 4.0  _MSC_VER == 1000
MSVC++ 2.0  _MSC_VER ==  900
MSVC++ 1.0  _MSC_VER ==  800
C/C++  7.0  _MSC_VER ==  700
C      6.0  _MSC_VER ==  600
```

Comment: Please note that `#define snprintf _snprintf` should never be used. It is unsafe as `_snprintf()` doesn't guarantee null-termination unlike C99's `snprintf()`. There are also other differences.

Comment: @cremno, Is this your comment or answer? I think you have misunderstood the whole point I am making here.

Comment: It's just a comment. Your answer is fine.

Comment: What about adding a stub to define the old name to allow old libs (that otherwise should work with any compiler version) to work?

Comment: I have this problem in a public library that needs to keep working with older VS versions. I wrapped the offending #define sprintf with #if _MSC_VER<1900 ... #endif    and yes I know this is obvious to many of you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.If I compile libs in VS 2013 it is not working in VS 2015. Same goes the other way. Can we make changes in lib source so one lib can work on both versions of VS?

Answer (score 5):

Just find the definition of `snprintf` in your code and undefine it while on `VS2015`.
Something like:

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1900 //vs2015 already have this function
#define snprintf _snprintf_s 
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

user1 is right

But even if you fix the problem this way, you'll probably face linker problems with prebuilt libraries.

The way to avoid this is to change platform toolset on all projects to **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)**

And in linker/input propry page add libcmt.lib to Ignore Specific Default libraries: **libcmt.lib**;libcmtd.lib;...

Comment: OP and others who look up this issue will likely not have the luxury to stick with VS2013 just to avoid an error.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck , user1185287 is not suggesting using VS2013, but to change the **toolset** used to compile, from the project properties (General Tab) directly from VS2015

Comment: I gotcha. The point, in its essence still stands, though. We all eventually have to "trade-up" :)