# VS 2015 compiling cocos2d-x 3.6 error Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration

Tags: cocos2d-x, visual-studio-2015

I compile cocos2d-x(version 3.6) using visual studio 2015, the error occurred, saying:

> fatal error C1189: #error: Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration

Almost the same question like this link
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754492/vs-2015-compiling-cocos2d-x-3-3-error-fatal-error-c1189-error-macro-definiti)

I try to follow the first answer and then search most results on cocos forum but also failed, I'm noob and really have no idea now ..

And here it's my source code where defined `snprintf` on header file `stdio.h`

```
#if defined snprintf
    // This definition of snprintf will generate "warning C4005: 'snprintf':     macro
    // redefinition" with a subsequent line indicating where the previous definition
    // of snprintf was.  This makes it easier to find where snprintf was defined.
    #pragma warning(push, 1)
    #pragma warning(1: 4005)
    #define snprintf Do not define snprintf as a macro
    #pragma warning(pop)
    #error Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
#endif
```

Could someone help me .. thanks!

Comment: This question was answered [here][1]:

consider doing this:
#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER < 1900))
  #define snprintf _snprintf
#endif

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27754492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same error trying to build libsndfile-1. I solved it by building using VS2013 instead of VS2015. (I think it should be possible to simply install VS2013 Build Tools and build from VS2015).

edit: to install the VS2013 build toolset, run the VS2015 installer and select 'Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools'