# Is there a way to determine target buffer size using _snprintf_s?

Tags: c++, windows

I currently use `_snprintf(NULL,0,fmtStr, Str..)` and it **returns the *required size***  of the buffer. I allocate them and then invoke `_snprintf` again to fill the buffer. But currently `_snprintf` is deprecated and `_snprintf_s` is the recommended function. But [according to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f30dzcf6.aspx) it doesn't seem to return length without allocating buffer before-hand.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Use `snprintf` ?  The C++ standard requires this function to exist, and it is not deprecated.

Comment: I don't think `_snprintf` is likely to be *removed*; the deprecation warning is for developers following the Security Development Lifecycle (where it's a banned function).

Comment: @M.M If MSVC does have `snprintf`, then it will also be marked as deprecated, as it's also banned in the SDL. (You can define a macro to disables these warnings, but I don't remember what it's called)

Comment: I'm struggling to see how `_snprintf_s` is supposed to be more secure than `snprintf`.

Comment: Vignesh: assuming you have *some* idea of the likely size of the string, you could write the string into a stack-based buffer (of fixed size) and then copy it to your newly allocated buffer.  (Or, of course, use C++ strings.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston ISO C++ `snprintf` does guarantee null-termination

Comment: @M.M: the Microsoft version doesn't: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx - guess they haven't caught up with that part of the standard either.  (Though I'm not sure how they're supposed to, since it would break backwards compatibility.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston that is `_snprintf`, not `snprintf` . I could agree with `_snprintf` being deprecated for `_snprintf_s`.

Comment: @M.M: ah, quite right.  [As it turns out,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288454.aspx) `_snprintf` is banned, but `snprintf` isn't - it's on the list of *recommended* functions!  (Which probably also means that they have implemented `snprintf` in the latest version after all, it just isn't in the version I'm using.)

Comment: Vignesh, what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Hi @Harry. I'm using VS2015 community-edition. Seems snprintf is a C99 standard and VS may not support it yet.

Comment: Think I'll allocate a buffer[MAX_PATH] and take it from there. This is inline with Harry's suggestion. Thanks for that!

Comment: It's the C++ standard that's relevant, because MS are trying to catch up to that one.  (Whereas if I understand correctly they've said they don't care about C99 and don't intend to ever support it.)  Are you `#include`ing `cstdio` or `stdio.h` ?  Is it a .c file or a .cpp file?

Comment: It's a CPP file. I had included stdio.h. I tried cstdio also- did not help.

Comment: The function should exist, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/27754829/886887

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Windows : Before VS2015:**
Make use of `_vscprintf()` to get the size of the expanded format string. Allocate memory and use `vsnprintf_s()` to perform the actual buffer fill.

**Gcc/Windows-VS2015 onward:**
(thanks to Harry-Johnston for pointing this out) `snprintf()` should be available. Use `snprintf(NULL,0,...)` to get the size, allocate mem, then `snprintf(buffer,..)` to perform the actual buffer fill.

Comment: For **wchar_t**  snprintf does not work.  I have tried to remplace 'snprint' with  **_snwprintf **', but I get a C4996 error.