# Is the output of snprintf guaranteed to be null-terminated with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, c99

I'm working with a C codebase in which my predecessor used:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  // Map to equivalent function
  #define snprintf sprintf_s
#endif
```

The codebase needs to compile on Linux (gcc/clang), OSX (gcc/clang) and Windows (VS). I've attempted to compile the code in Visual Studio 2015 for the first time. Previously Visual Studio 2010 had been used. I encountered the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754492/vs-2015-compiling-cocos2d-x-3-3-error-fatal-error-c1189-error-macro-definiti) and was able to compile using a clue from the accepted answer:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #if _MSC_VER<1900
    #define snprintf sprintf_s
  #endif
#endif
```

The project compiles now with Visual Studio 2015 and clang on OSX. However, I'm concerned about a statement in the [sprintf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) documentation:

**Unlike snprintf, sprintf_s guarantees that the buffer will be null-terminated (unless the buffer size is zero).**

If Visual Studio is including a C99 compliant version of `snprintf`, shouldn't the buffer be guaranteed to be null-terminated?

I wrote a small program to evaluate the behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buf[5];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "abcdef");
    printf("buffer: %s\n", buf);
    printf("size of buffer: %lu\n", strlen(buf));
    printf("last character a null terminator?: %s\n",
        (strcmp(&buf[4], "\0") == 0) ? "yes" : "no");
    return 0;
}
```

I built and ran the program on OSX, and Windows with Visual Studio 2015.

On OSX, the output is:

```
~$c99 main.c
~$./a.out 
buffer: abcd
size of buffer: 4
last character a null terminator?: yes
```

On Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015 the output is

```
> printf_evaluation.exe
buffer: abcd
size of buffer: 4
last character a null terminator?: yes
```

Doesn't that demonstrate the the output is in fact null-terminated, and suggest that the MSDN documentation is incorrect? Is my example too trivial? Are there cases when the output of `snprintf` might not be NULL terminated with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: I think, they meant **Unlike _snprintf**, which indeed doesn't null-terminate. VS doesn't know snprintf at all (except as a macro for sprintf_s)

Comment: I suspect it's a documentation bug rather than anything unusual/wrong with the implementation of `snprintf()` in visual studio.

Comment: Microsoft's 1980s implementation of `snprintf` was different to the C99 Standard one; that's the root of all these issues.  IDK when (if ever) VS runtime would have been updated to use the C99 version.

Comment: MS have never made any effort to comply with C99 - what makes you think "Visual Studio is including a C99 compliant version of snprintf" ?

Comment: suggest, for verification of what actually happens....  write a small program that passes an 'overlenght' buffer to snprintf() then use the debugger to see what is actually placed in the resulting buffer.

Comment: Wow, your predecessor's macro is anything but "equivalent". Not only would it have been necessary to use `_snprintf_s()` instead of `sprintf_s()` to avoid an (artificial) crash, but the return value would have been wrong too (until VS2015, only `_scprintf()` unconditionally returned the "full" length).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) would always nul terminate the buffer as long as the second argument to it is greater than zero. So yes, the MSDN documentation is wrong.

[*From C11 standard, snprintf():*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5)

> The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output
>   is written into an array (speciﬁed by argument s) rather than to a
>   stream. **If n is zero, nothing is written**, and s may  be  a  null 
>   pointer. Otherwise,  output  characters  beyond  the n-1st  are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and **a null character
>   is written at the end of the characters actually written into the
>   array.** If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the
>   behavior is undefined.

(emphasis mine).

Comment: The MSDN documentation would be describing the behaviour of MS tools, which may differ from the ISO C standard. AFAIK , MS have never made any claim to support C99 (let alone C11)

Comment: See [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx): snprintf and vsnprintf Are Now Implemented: The C99 snprintf and vsnprintf functions have been implemented.

Comment: @M.M [The latest visual studio provides nearly complete support for C99.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx)

Comment: I ran the example with MSVC 9.0 and 15.0. The earlier one does not have `snprintf` only `_snprintf`, using the latter both compilers produced code that wrote 5 characters to the string and did not terminate it. However MSVC 15.0 does have `snprintf` which behaves as OP says. MSVC documentation for [_snprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) says *"this function does not guarantee NULL termination"*, and that set of documentation does not mention `snprintf`. So yes, there is a documentation fault, and the two versions `snprintf` and `_snprintf` do not behave the same.