# Error when pip installing CRFsuite in Python 3 Windows 10 x86

Tags: python, c++, windows

I'm trying to install [CRFsuite](https://python-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to my Python 3 based on Windows 10 x86 while an Error occured, please see below. At start, it was missing `vcvars32.bat` but I managed to solve it by installing *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015* including *Common tools for visual c++ 2015*. After that, it starts to run but this came out: `error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`.

The problem seems to be defining the `snprintf` in `stdio.h`, I have tried solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754492/vs-2015-compiling-cocos2d-x-3-3-error-fatal-error-c1189-error-macro-definiti) by adding a few lines of code in `stdio.h` but not working.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1927): fatal error C1189: #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
```

Please see more details below. Kindly hope anyone would give me a hand. Thanks in advance.

```
[Python3] C:\>cd "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin"

[Python3] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin>VCVARS32
[Python3] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin>pip install python-crfsuite
Collecting python-crfsuite
  Using cached python-crfsuite-0.8.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: python-crfsuite
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-crfsuite ... error
  Complete output from command f:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dwkmw7ii\\python-crfsuite\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph_uhnrfipip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
  copying pycrfsuite\_dumpparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
  copying pycrfsuite\_logparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
  copying pycrfsuite\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
  running build_ext
  building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\pycrfsuite
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\crf
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\crf\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\swig
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\cqdb
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\cqdb\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\liblbfgs
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\liblbfgs\lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -Icrfsuite/win32 -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /EHsc /Tppycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.obj
  _pycrfsuite.cpp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -Icrfsuite/win32 -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /EHsc /Tppycrfsuite/trainer_wrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\pycrfsuite/trainer_wrapper.obj
  trainer_wrapper.cpp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -Icrfsuite/win32 -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /EHsc /Tccrfsuite/lib/crf/src\crf1d_context.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite/lib/crf/src\crf1d_context.obj
  crf1d_context.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(262): warning C4005: 'isfinite': macro redefinition
  crfsuite/include/os.h(49): note: see previous definition of 'isfinite'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1925): warning C4005: 'snprintf': macro redefinition
  crfsuite/include/os.h(50): note: see previous definition of 'snprintf'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1927): fatal error C1189: #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for python-crfsuite
  Running setup.py clean for python-crfsuite
Failed to build python-crfsuite
Installing collected packages: python-crfsuite
  Running setup.py install for python-crfsuite ... error
    Complete output from command f:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dwkmw7ii\\python-crfsuite\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-sd7k3msy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
    copying pycrfsuite\_dumpparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
    copying pycrfsuite\_logparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
    copying pycrfsuite\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pycrfsuite
    running build_ext
    building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\pycrfsuite
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\crf
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\crf\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\swig
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\cqdb
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite\lib\cqdb\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\liblbfgs
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\liblbfgs\lib
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -Icrfsuite/win32 -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /EHsc /Tppycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.obj
    _pycrfsuite.cpp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -Icrfsuite/win32 -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /EHsc /Tppycrfsuite/trainer_wrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\pycrfsuite/trainer_wrapper.obj
    trainer_wrapper.cpp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -Icrfsuite/win32 -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include -If:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /EHsc /Tccrfsuite/lib/crf/src\crf1d_context.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\crfsuite/lib/crf/src\crf1d_context.obj
    crf1d_context.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(262): warning C4005: 'isfinite': macro redefinition
    crfsuite/include/os.h(49): note: see previous definition of 'isfinite'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1925): warning C4005: 'snprintf': macro redefinition
    crfsuite/include/os.h(50): note: see previous definition of 'snprintf'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1927): fatal error C1189: #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "f:\python3\anaconda3\envs\python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dwkmw7ii\\python-crfsuite\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-sd7k3msy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dwkmw7ii\python-crfsuite\

[Python3] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post regarding precisely why the compilation fails. [VS 2015 compiling cocos2d-x 3.3 error "fatal error C1189: #error: Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754492/vs-2015-compiling-cocos2d-x-3-3-error-fatal-error-c1189-error-macro-definiti/27754829#27754829)

WRT quick fixes - we were able to get a successful build on Python 3.4, so perhaps consider using that if this isn't a major project?