# An error happened when compiling the FreeImage library as static linking?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-linking

I'm trying to compile the [FreeImage v3.17.0](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) library by using Visual Studio 2015 to get the static library file but there are some problems.

The library package comes as follow:

[image]

I used the `FreeImage.2013` file to compile the library, and after the compilation is done I found this result `Build: 16 succeeded, 4 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped`.
the FreeImage library itself did not compile but the other third-party libraries have been compiled, but there's an error appear:   `Error C1189 #error: Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration ..\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h`

**How to resolve that problem?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another problem similar to my problem but in a different subject. [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754492/vs-2015-compiling-cocos2d-x-3-3-error-fatal-error-c1189-error-macro-definiti).

**Explain the problem:**

> Until now, many libraries and programs used `snprintf()` function by
>   defining it as `_snprintf()`, since `_snprintf()` was supported.
>
> ```
> #define snprintf _snprintf
> ```
>
> `snprintf()` became recognized in visual studio 2015 (v140).   So,
>   `snprintf()` is now officially supported, We should never define it.
>   Doing it will overshadow new `snprintf()` function defined in stdio.h.

**The Solution:**
Search for this line `#define snprintf _snprintf` in all projects files and make it a comment (put `//` at the beginning of the line).

An example:

[image]